# Why does autowiring jdbctemplate result in a cyclic dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

The following code produces a cyclic dependency error.

```
   @Controller
    public class Controllers {

        @Autowired
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
        @ResponseBody
        public String map(){
            String sql = "INSERT INTO persons " +
                    "(id, name, surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            Connection conn = null;
            jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO persons (id, name, surname) VALUES (1, \'Name\', \'Surname\')");

            return "";
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .username("root")
                    .password("root")
                    .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people")
                    .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .build();
        }


The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  controllers (field org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate controllers.Controllers.jdbcTemplate)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  dataSource
└─────┘
```

but if I do not autowire jdbctemplate and initialize it normally

```
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
```

then no errors are produced

I have the following gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE")
     compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
   compile(group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

What is the reason behind the cyclic dependency?

Comment: Because there is an `@Bean` method for the datasource, the datasource is required for the `JdbcTemplate` but the enclosing class is needed to create a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency because the `JdbcTemplate` needs a `DataSource` but for the `DataSource` to be created an instance of the `Controllers` is needed, but because that needs a `JdbcTemplate` it cannot be constructed (due to the cyclic dependency).

You are using Spring Boot but apparently trying hard not to. Remove your `@Bean` method for the `DataSource` and add the following to the `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

With this spring boot will provide a preconfigured `DataSource` for you.

**Pro-Tip**
Something else you are mixing versions of Spring Boot 1.5.2 and 1.5.3 never mix versions of a framework as that is trouble waiting to happen. Just remove all versions, and assuming you are using Spring Boot with Gradle properly, you will have a single managed version.